# How to get cursor position in Edit Control MFC?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Is there any way to know the current cursor position in the Edit Control?

I have a scenario where I need to insert text in the current cursor position.

**Note:** I'm implementing the logic in C++.

Answer (score 4):

You don't strictly need to query for the cursor position, if you want to insert text at the current location. The [CEdit::ReplaceSel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cedit-class#replacesel) can be used to do that, as explained in the documentation:

> If there is no current selection, the replacement text is inserted at the current cursor location.

Depending on your specific requirements you would have to deal with the case, when there is a non-empty selection. The most natural implementation would be to replace the current selection. That's what users expect, and you wouldn't need to implement any additional code logic.

If you would rather insert text at the current cursor location in case there currently is a selection, you can remove the selection without altering the current cursor position by calling [CEdit::SetSel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cedit-class#setsel):

```
m_edit.SetSel(-1, 0);
```

Comment: Good interpretation of what the question actually is.

Comment: @acraig5075: When 9 out of 10 questions are [XY Problems](http://xyproblem.info), you just stop looking at the question, and try to figure out, what problem the OP is *really* trying to solve. This question is better than most in that it actually discloses that problem.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the documentation makes this quite easy. You will use [`GetCaretPos()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-6.0/aa249280(v=vs.60)) and [`CharFromPos()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7yhsd2b.aspx#cedit__charfrompos) in conjunction.

```
return m_edit.CharFromPos(m_edit.GetCaretPos());
```

Comment: @RevanthRao: That's not how you say *"Thank you!"* at Stack Overflow. Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)